# Как перевести URL в BitMapImage асинхронно

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть ссылка. Есть функция, в которую передается эта ссылка. Она возвращает битмап, но не асихнронно, из за чего UI зависает. Как сделать это асинхронно, без конвертера в отдельном классе.

```
public async Task<BitmapImage> converter(string url)
    {

            var bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.UriSource = new Uri(url);
            bi.EndInit();
            return bi;
        

    }
```

Comment: А зачем вам это? Контрол Image можно напрямую вязать к ссылке, он сам создаст и сам загрузит картинку. Вы делаете странные вещи.

Comment: как это сделать? можете рассказать?

Comment: Для начала надо узнать - что именно сделать?

Comment: привязать image к ссылке

Comment: `<Image Source="ссылка" />` в XAML

Comment: а че так можно было чтоли? вот я глупец!

Comment: но добавляется не асинхронно, юи виснет

Comment: Все там асинхронно, ничего виснуть не должно. Опишите общую задачу, покажите разметку и код прямо в вопросе. Будем вас знакомить с WPF.

Comment: мне не надо знакомства. я подвязал напрямую к ссылке. но он же пока ее прогружает UI виснет. оформите как ответ - поставлю галку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берем какой-нибудь класс и реализуем на нем `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Наследуем от него еще один какой-нибудь класс и добавляем в него свойство-ссылку

```
public class MyClass : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string url;

    public string Url
    {
        get => url; 
        set
        {
            url = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Модель данных готова. С такой модели интерфейс умеет обновляться сам через привязку данных.

В XAML

```xml
<Image Source="{Binding Url}"/>
```

Теперь в коде окна

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MyClass data;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        data = new MyClass();
        DataContext = data;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        data.Url = "https://ссылка";
    }
}
```

Вот так ничего виснуть не будет.

Comment: Почему вы ивет клика не вынесли во viewmidel и оставили во view? Я имею ввиду ICommand и привязка к нему

Comment: @Frehzy чтобы не усложнять решение.

Comment: А, понял. Спасибо